# Scalar product of vectors with different basis?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, change-of-basis

Let's say I have this scalar product with the basis in both Cartesian and cylindrical coordinates.
$$ê_y\cdotê_\rho$$

Do I need to convert one of them to the other basis, e.g. convert $ê_\rho$ to $cos\phiê_x+sin\phiê_y$ and then perform the scalar product $(0,1,0)\cdot(cos\phi, sin\phi,0)=(0,sin\phi,0)$?

Or how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scalar product must be a scalar, so it is just $\sin \phi$. You can see this by converting one vector from cylindrical to cartesian co-ordinates *or* by using the co-ordinate free definition of the scalar product which is

$\overrightarrow{a} \cdot \overrightarrow{b} = |\overrightarrow{a}||\overrightarrow{b}| \cos \theta$

where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$. In you example $|\overrightarrow{a}|=|\overrightarrow{b}=1$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\phi$.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's just sin(phi). **Scalar** product! Okay, thank you, so to convert is the answer (or use the _coordinate free definition of scalar product_). If I was to convert to cartesian to cylindrical the answer would always be the same I guess?

Comment: Yes, but the formula for scalar product in cylindrical co-ordinates becomes more complex. It is $(r_1, \theta_1, z_1) \cdot (r_2, \theta_2, z_2) = r_1r_2 \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) + z_1z_2$